# CDI HK2 Error in JaxRS Application

Tags: cdi, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, weld, hk2

I wrote an JaxRS Application for Glassfish 4. It uses Jackson 2. I can build it without any problems, but when i deploy it i get one or more of the following 4 Errors.

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>]
```

and/or

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous. Name JerseyClassAnalyzer resolves to beans [Managed Bean ...
```

and/or

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider] ...
```

and/or

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref<ContainerRequest>]
```

As i know the last exception could be thrown when glassfish tries to load a class twice?

I uploaded a screenshot of my direct and indirect Dependencies. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEtb1.png

regarding other solutions i tried to add `<scope>provided</scope>` to the packages which included these classes. --> no success

Do you have any idea?

### **EDIT 1:**

my ResourceConfig:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register( JacksonFeature.class );
    }

    private void addMyResources() {
        //a lot of resources.
    }
}
```

to enable Jackson 2:

```
public class JacksonFeature implements Feature {

    public boolean configure( final FeatureContext context ) {

        String postfix = '.' + context.getConfiguration().getRuntimeType().name().toLowerCase();

        context.property( CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + postfix, true );

        context.register( JsonParseExceptionMapper.class );
        context.register( JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class );
        context.register( JacksonJsonProvider.class, MessageBodyReader.class, MessageBodyWriter.class );

        return true;
    }
}
```

a lot of entities like that:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class, property = "id", scope=Address.class)
//the JsonIdentityInfo is the reason i need Jackson 2
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    @Embedded
    private Coordinate coordinate;
    //getters, setters , etc.
}
```

then i have a lot of DAO's like that:

```
@Stateless
public class AddressDao extends GenericDao {
    public Address getAddress(long id){
        return em.find(Address.class, id);
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses(){
        List<Address> address = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Address a", Address.class).getResultList();
        return address;
    }
}
```

and a lot of resources like that:

```
@Path("dummy")
@Stateless
public class DummyResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @Inject userAuth user;
    @Inject addressDao AddressDao;

    public DummyResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return AddressDao.getAddresses();
    }

}
```

### **EDIT 2:**

I created a new test project. as soon as i add a dependency to org.glassfish.jersey.server i get the errors.

### **EDIT 3:**

i made a test application with the error:

http://www.file-upload.net/download-8459084/testApplication_20131229.rar.html

Comment: i'm deploying it as a **war**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using CDI in your application you can do this when deploying your application:

asadmin deploy --property implicitCdiEnabled=false

That will turn off the implicit class scanning that is done by CDI when an application is deployed.  More information about default usage of CDI can be found here: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java

If you are using CDI you might want to try adding a beans.xml to the Jersey jar in your application with this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

Comment: well i'm using CDI and i need it.

Comment: the jar is read only. or did you mean my application? when i add it to my application, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I guess I'd need to understand exactly what you are deploying.  Are you deploying an ear or a war?  In either case you probably need to repackage just jersey into your own ear with the above beans.xml in order to turn CDI off for that component.  Truthfully Jersey should ship out-of-the-box with such a beans.xml for just this issue, you should probably open a Jira with them

Comment: okay, i will describe in my initial request what i do in my application.

Comment: I need to use the org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig and  org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties. should i put the beans.xml in both of these?

Comment: i added a link to a test application with the same error maybe it helps

Comment: I can't seem to get access to your test application.  Could be that it has to do with the company firewall

Comment: well. where could i upload it for you? br